# Improve performance of a last status retrieval from history table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I want to retrieve the latest status for an item from a history table. History table will have a record of all status changes for an item. The query must be quick to run.

Below is the query that I use to get the latest status per item

```
    SELECT item_history.*
    FROM item_history
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at, item_id
      FROM item_history
      GROUP BY item_id
    ) as latest_status
      on latest_status.item_id = item_history.item_id 
        and latest_status.created_at = item_history.created_at
  WHERE item_history.status_id = 1
    and item_history.created_at BETWEEN "2020-12-16" AND "2020-12-23"
```

I've tried putting query above into another inner join to link data with an item:

```
SELECT *
FROM `items`
INNER JOIN ( [query from above] )
WHERE items.category_id = 3
```

**Notes** about item_history table, I have index on the following columns: status_id, creatd_at and listing_id. I have also turned 3 of those into a compound primary key.

My issue is that MySQL keeps scanning the full table to grab `MAX(created_at)` which is a very slow operation, even tho I only have 3 million records within the history table.

Query plan as follows:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | items | NULL | ref | "PRIMARY,district" | district | 18 | const | 694 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | item_history | NULL | ref | "PRIMARY,status_id,created_at,item_history_item_id_index" | PRIMARY | 9 | "main.items.id,const" | 1 | 100.00 | "Using where" |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | NULL | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 14 | "func,main.items.id" | 10 | 100.00 | "Using where; Using index" |
| 2 | DERIVED | item_history | NULL | range | "PRIMARY,status_id,created_at,item_history_item_id_index" | item_history_item_id_index | 8 | NULL | 2751323 | 100.00 | "Using index" |

Comment: The optimal "groupwise-max" code is found here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: @RickJames  you are amazing as always! Thanks for writing all those articles - they come very useful.

Comment: It's been a fun challenge.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to retrieve the latest status for an item from a history table.

If you want the results for just one item, then use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select *
from item_history
where item_id = ? and created_at between '2020-12-16' and '2020-12-23'
order by created_at desc limit 1
```

This query would benefit an index on `(item_id, created_at)`.

If you want the latest status *per item*, I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from item_history h
where created_at = (
    select max(h1.created_at) 
    from item_history h1
    where h1.item_id = h.item_id
      and h1.created_at between '2020-12-16' and '2020-12-23'
)
```

The same index should be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Using window function MySQL 8.0.14+:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) r
  FROM item_history
  WHERE item_history.status_id = 1
    and item_history.created_at BETWEEN '2020-12-16' AND '2020-12-23'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte WHERE r = 1;
```

Index on (item_id,created_at) will also help